# ple:Android Multitouch "pointer index out of range" - Why?

Tags: android, touch

I know there are some other threads on that topic, but there is no question that reduces the problem to a few lines of code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int count = event.getPointerCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        int id = event.getPointerId(i);
        event.getX(id); // Exception here
    }

}
```

The code simply gets the number of pointers, asks for the pointer-id and uses it to read the x-value of the pointer.

The code throws "IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range" when I use more than one finger.

The Exception is thrown with all possible actions ("ACTION_DOWN", "ACTION_POINTER_DOWN", "ACTION_UP", "ACTION_POINTER_UP" and "ACTION_MOVE")

Example:

I put down finger one, then down finger two, then up finger one => every move of finger two fails now.

Complete onTouchEvent for testing:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int action = (event.getActionMasked() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK);
    int count = event.getPointerCount();

    String actionStr = null;

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            actionStr = "down";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            actionStr = "up";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            actionStr = "move";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            actionStr = "pointer up";
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            actionStr = "pointer down";
            break;
    }

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            int id = event.getPointerId(i);
            event.getX(id);
            //event.getY(id);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("_FAIL_", actionStr);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Which line is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that:

```
event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(id));
```

**Edit**

From [Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/gestures/multi.html):

> The order in which individual pointers appear within a motion event is undefined. Thus the index of a pointer can change from one event to the next, but the pointer ID of a pointer is guaranteed to remain constant as long as the pointer remains active. Use the getPointerId() method to obtain a pointer's ID to track the pointer across all subsequent motion events in a gesture. Then for successive motion events, use the findPointerIndex() method to obtain the pointer index for a given pointer ID in that motion event.

I hope it helps.

Comment: event.findPointerIndex(id) is the same as i, not?